# Can I share ~1k of dynamically updated data between HTML5/JS pages using only apache2?

Tags: json, apache2, persistence

I have an HTML5/Javascript web site. There is a form which updates JSON data. There are other pages which I would like to load that JSON data dynamically. I know how to do this via Tomcat/JSP but I'd like to keep this site solely apache2. Is there a way to persist and read the JSON data? It is ok if the data is temporal and is lost upon an apache2 bounce.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to store the JSON data in localStorage/sessionStorage on the client side.

Store Item:

```
localStorage.setItem('storedItem', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

Retrieve Item:

```
var json = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedItem'));
```

[JavaScript Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/Guide/DOM/Storage)

Comment: That may be useful, but it can't help me share data between users.